# MySQL PHP wildcard? fetching column from tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have a html form what lets the user's choose from a list certain people's email. One the user chooses those emails and hits submit, in a MySQL table "UserChosenEmails" column "email" those emails get added. This table only has emails column. Now I have another table named "UserInfo" with 2 columns, email and number. UserInfo table has emails and numbers of ALL emails not just the ones the user choose. What I am trying to do here is fetch the numbers of the emails in "UserChosenEmails" but this column only has specific emails but no phone numbers so how can I take all the emails in "UserChosenEmails" and fetch their numbers from "UserInfo"'s number column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want an SQL [JOIN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29) query:

```
SELECT UserChosenEmails.email, UserInfo.number
FROM UserChosenEmails
INNER JOIN UserInfo on UserChosenEmails.email = UserInfo.email
```

Comment: Inner Join is not a necessity.

Comment: Why not? Your syntax below is the 'lazy' join syntax, which should be avoided at all costs.

Comment: Ya, but it's shorter and easier to understand :P

Comment: I find this one easier to understand but the one below uses less code so I want to accept both answer :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this query (innerjoin is not necessary)

```
SELECT number FROM UserChosenEmails, UsersInfos WHERE UserChosenEmails.email = UsersInfos.email;
```

Comment: PS: there is only 1 column in UserChosenEmails. That column is "email"

Comment: Ya, but that doesn't change anything. (or does it)

Comment: oh because you say SELECT number from UserChosenEmails, UserInfos, only userInfos has the number column. If thats how its suppose to be MySQL is weird :P

Comment: `SELECT number from UserChosenEmails, UserInfos` is the same as ` SELECT UserInfos.number from UserChosenEmails, UserInfos` because only `UserInfos` has got a `number` column.